# how to remotely configure my mobile game starter pack?

Tags: android, mobile, starter-kits

I have a mobile game in development, and like many others, I want to give my users a default set of starter items (e.g. coins + sword). But I want to be able to change this, depending on where the user came from (e.g. different for Chinese user vs. Russian user, but there may be other segments).

Any easy way of doing it? Currently, I'm evaluating [this Trophit tool](http://www.trophit.com) on iOS/Android which allows me to create ad campaign tracking links which I can later configure starter items for each campaign. Hence I make the "twist" and use campaigns to identify a certain user segment because I control the campaign target audience on my ad networks and get all analytics on my tracker dashboard... It's pretty straightforward, but I am not sure maybe there are other solutions as well or maybe someone can provide more info on experience with that tool?

Appreciate your feedback, thanks

p.s. as u see I'm new to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can host a XML configuration file somewhere and have the game download it the first time it is run. Something like

```
   <config>
         <startkit>
              <item name="item1"/>
              <item name="item2"/>
              ...
         </startkit>
    </config>
```

You can then parse this xml and get the info you want. And if you change your mind later on, the file can be changed and the app behavior changes. Also, using google play, you can deploy a different APK for every region, each with it's different url to a config file. Or you can have the user pick his region and then parse the corresponding configuration file

Another option is to detect device language and then pick the best configuration option. But this is not 100% reliable. I keep my device in English although I don't live in an english speaking country.

Comment: Ouch, hosting that xml does not help me map each item to certain audience segments, different APKs is by far non-dynamic (I should be able to change the starter packs on the fly), and hardcoding segments (e.g by region) is also not dynamic enough because the segments change: sometimes it's by country, sometimes its by country and gender, sometimes only by ad network, and so on... Seems like trying to do it myself is a real hassle for what I need, any 3rd party solutions out there I can try except Trophit?

Comment: Actualy it does... I provided you with ways to determine the type of audience that is using your device. And for example, you can have the user fill a form at the start of the game. How else are you going to get all this info, like age and gender for example? In general, I am against using 3rd party tools and using your own code as much as possible. It's not that much work. But in the end, it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Sth important: believing in middleware or not - doesn't matter, publishers require I use 3rd party trackers so I might as well make good use of its extensions (e.g. Trophit). Determining audiences in hardcoded ways as well as building a system to analyze this information with reports, etc - that's way out of my focus of making the game... Forms: users don't fill those, u know that :) I think using my tracker/adnets to manage my audience and using Trophit to link it to starter packs makes sense, I'll continue evaluating & share insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Trophit seemed OK for me, here's my POC:
I am using Adjust tracker, so I took Trophit's client-side integration for Android/iOS and followed their [integration guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-Un-FH_EPg)
Then I created a "tracker" (campaign) in my Adjust dashboard for each audience segment, e.g. "china trophit_cmp_xxx" (for each trophit starter pack voucher id), and made a test on one of the adjust tracking links (since the game is not yet released I had to run in Adjust sandbox mode) - as soon as I opened the game, I got the extra coins that trophit verified for that campaign for my user.

Took me about 2 hours, I will continue to work on it and see if there are any other things I can use there.

thanks!